# Set UsbDeviceListener javax.usb/usb4java

Tags: java, usb, listener, addeventlistener

I tried to set the UsbDeviceListener but nothing happens when I disconnect the device nor when I create a new file on the device.
Can someone tell me where is the problem in my code?

```
public static void listPeripherique(UsbHub hub) {
 List perepheriques = hub.getAttachedUsbDevices();
 Iterator iterator = perepheriques.iterator();
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   UsbDevice perepherique = (UsbDevice) iterator.next();
   perepherique.addUsbDeviceListener(new UsbDeviceListener() {

        @Override
        public void usbDeviceDetached(UsbDeviceEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("connect " + arg0);

        }

        @Override
        public void errorEventOccurred(UsbDeviceErrorEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("disconect " + arg0);

        }

        @Override
        public void dataEventOccurred(UsbDeviceDataEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("new data on " + arg0);  
        }
    });
  }
  if (perepherique.isUsbHub()) {
    listPeripherique((UsbHub) perepherique);
  }
}
```

Edit: It's work only for usb Detached.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind giving use more details on your environment (Linux, Win, OSX) and what kind of USB device (Stick, Gamepad, DVD-Burner, Dongle, iP(a|o)d, iPhone, Smartphone)? However, if you use Windows, it seems the driver is out-of-date: [JSR80](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/): This is an ABANDONED Windows implementation. it does not work, it needs a kernel driver.

Keep us posted on your project and progress.

### Edit

I tried it with my Logitech Wingman controller and I can confirm that only `usbDeviceDetached` events are raised. I think the driver is really outdated :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is working correctly.

Your code iterates once over all currently connected devices and registers a device listener on it. When the device is disconnected then the `usbDeviceDetached` event is triggered. The other two events are triggered after data is transfered from or to the device by your own program or when an error occurred when your program tried to communicate with the device.

*javax-usb* can't monitor data transfers made by other programs. Maybe this is what you expected? For this you need a special USB monitor tool like `usbmon` on Linux.